# Mediawiki SessionProvider $_SESSION variable is empty

Tags: php, session, mediawiki

I'm trying to implement a *SessionProvider* auth plugin for a mediawiki install.

I'm trying to integrate with an existing auth system that uses `$_SESSION` to indicate that a user is logged in, however any method I try, the resulting `$_SESSION` variable that I get inside the class' `provideSessionInfo` function is empty.

Previously this was done with a `onUserLoadFromSession` hook (that contained the bulk of the logic code below), but the update appears to have broken actually looking at the existing `$_SESSION`:

```
public function provideSessionInfo(WebRequest $request)
{
    // $_SESSION is hidden away per-request, but $request->getSession likes to call this function (yay infinite loops)
    if (!isset($_SESSION['memberid'])) {
        return null;
    }
    $memberid = $_SESSION['memberid'];

    $mr_user = MyRadio_User::getInstance($memberid);
    $user = User::newFromName($memberid);
    $dbr = wfGetDB(DB_REPLICA);
    $s = $dbr->selectRow('user', ['user_id'], ['user_name' => $memberid]);
    if ($s === false) {
        return null;
    } else {
        $user->mName = $memberid;
        $user->mId = $user->idForName();
        $user->loadFromDatabase();
        $user->saveSettings();
    }

    if ($mr_user->hasAuth(AUTH_WIKIADMIN) && !in_array('sysop', $user->getGroups())) {
        $user->addGroup('sysop');
    }

    $user->mTouched = wfTimestampnow();

    return new SessionInfo(SessionInfo::MAX_PRIORITY, [
        'provider' => $this,
        'persisted' => true,
        'userInfo' => UserInfo::newFromUser($user, true),
    ]);
}
```

If I hardcode `$memberid`, the function and the session provider works fine, but I just can't seem to find a way to transfer the session from one PHP "application" to another.

Adding debugging shows the `PHPSESSID` variable still set in the cookie, but for whatever reason it can't be pulled out into an actual session object. I've tried various `session_start()` style methods to no effect.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but the documentation for this stuff is just a basic wiki page and the raw generated doxygen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session handling is not a good way of cross-application communication. MediaWiki uses its own session handling, which means there is no connection between `$_SESSION` in MediaWiki and `$_SESSION` in your application at all. The first will be populated from MediaWiki's object cache (as configured by [`$wgSessionCacheType`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSessionCacheType)), the other from PHP session files or whatever.

If you really do not have a better way to pass data, you'll have to write a custom access class which can be called by your provider, which will save the current session handler, install a null session handler (which restores PHP's native session handling which will hopefully be interoperable with the other application), start the session, fetch the session data, restore the original session handler, and probably start the session again.

Comment: I figured this may well be the answer. Can you suggest some other  better way of passing the data, other than using sessions?

Comment: The nice way is to expose some kind of API in the auth system which can be securely queried for login status (e.g. redirect the user there, and it should redirect back with some kind of proof, say a signed JWT). That's how many SSO systems work. The benefit is that you are not required to use the same domain for all your applications (although you have to e mindful about cross-domain browser limitations such as WebKit's [tracking prevention](https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention/) if you use separate domains).

Comment: Or you can just put everything on the same domain and use a cookie with a name known to both applications (with some kind of encryption or signing to protect against tampering) to share data. Or use the cookie to pass some storage key and use a shared storage (memcached, a shared database etc). At which point you have pretty much reimplemented session handling (except for the convenience of auto-registering everything in superglobals) but in a way that's fully under your control and so safe to share between multiple applications.